# Is there a way to see what files have been accessed via http in Linux or apache logs?

Tags: linux, apache, logging, ubuntu, webserver

I'm trying to see how many times a flash (SWF) file has been accessed.

I've looked in `/var/log/apache2/access.log` but that appears empty. Is this the correct place to be looking? If so, do I need to enable it in `etc/syslog.conf`?

I've also checked `/var/log/syslog` but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: My access log is located under /var/log/httpd. You could check there as well?

Comment: I'm sure people on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) can guide you better. Marked for migration.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your Apache configuration. Look for CustomLog and LogFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that I'm stupid and I'm running Python/Django on `nginx` rather than `apache` so the access logs were in there instead.

Thanks to those who took a look.